# Typescript definitions for core-js@3

Tags: typescript, core-js

I need to use some core-js@3 polyfills from within TypeScript. However, `@types/core-js` provides definitions for core-js@2.5 only, and it seems that core-js@3 is sufficiently different from 2 that most type definitions are outdated.
Is there some accepted workaround to this?

Comment: Exact same issue here. Things like `structuredClone` are not yet defined in @types, causing problems for TS. Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

A shim can help here. For instance, if you need typings for `structuredClone`:

```js
// shims/core-js.d.ts

declare module 'core-js/actual/structured-clone' {
    export default function structuredClone<T>(value: T): T;
}
```

Note: This omits the `transfer` property as it's not something I personally intend to use.

Comment: Instead of providing a local shim, why don't people update the @types/core-js itself? ...